# Locating pictures with pyautogui library in python

Tags: python, opencv, bots

I was working with the function pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.png'), this function will search for the img in the screen and return 4 coordinates, it was working fine now the function doesn't detect any image. I use python version 3.11.2, is there any other way to locate an image?

I tried using the openCV library by importing cv2 and added a confidence parametre to my function, I tried uninstalling python and openCV.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.